# Issues with Cron Jobs in CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress, cron-job

we have been running Civicrm with cron jobs set up sucessfully for a couple of months without any problems until yesterday when we started getting emails with the following

Warning: file_get_contents(https://latest.civicrm.org/stable.php?format=summary): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /home/customer/www/[example]/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/VersionCheck.php on line 304

[example] has our website on it.

We contacted our webhost and they couldn't find any issues.

Could someone point us in the right direction on what this issue is and how to solve it?

thanks for the help, it's very much appreciated.

cheers,
JD

Comment: What version of CiviCRM are you using?

Comment: Sorry, should have included this in the post. CiviCRM : 5.15.1
Wordpress:5.2.2

Comment: The message is listing a connection timeout while trying to send the Version Infos of your Civicrm Installation (and extensions). Do you have access to some server logs from your hoster?